# animation.FuncAnimation works fine with with python3, lag with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I have the following code taken from the example of the website : http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html

The library imported:

`import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation`

The main function used:
`anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=300, interval=50, blit=False)`

Because I need to remain in python 2.7, I was hoping to execute this script with 2.7
The problem is under python3 the animation is really smooth, and under python 2.7 I basically have only the 2 extreme graph image looping.

I have tried playing with the parameters of frames and interval but it does not seem to work.

Why? Is there a solution to stay under 2.7 and keep the smoothness of the animation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (it works fine for me):

```
1. blit=True (greatly enhances the animation).
```

If you want more improving, try to save on file like this:

```
2.1 ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, YOUR_ITERABLE,
                      interval=1, blit=True, init_func=init)
2.2 ani.save('teste2.mp4',fps=15)
```

Note that in 2.1 I don't use frames=300. For me, setting interval=1 and manipulating fps at 2.2 allows me to manipulate the time rate of the picture.